# MongoDB doesn't initiate in my command line

Tags: mongodb

After installing MongoDB and writing the markup, I wanted to run my server on node.

This is the error I get when I initiate my MongoDB on the terminal. Please help

> mongod
>       2015-11-17T12:14:34.541+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:13 Permission denied
>       2015-11-17T12:14:34.542+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
>       2015-11-17T12:14:34.542+0530 I -        [initandlisten]
>
> ***aborting after fassert() failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things that you can do.

delete the sock file:

`sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

or try running as root:

`sudo mongod`

Also try creating a data folder in `/` owned by your user:

```
mkdir /data
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /data
```

And then running:

```
mongod
```

After deleting the sock file.